# How to convert IHtmlString(@Html) in views to properties in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, binding, properties

I am in the middle of refactoring/improving some performance related issues on UI. The project is in ASP.NET MVC. Typically the .cshtml files have all the bindings setup.

There are some bindings like this :

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='accessible' title='@Messages.GetMessageText(GetPortData(), 359608)'></a>
```

which I changed to a property.

```
public string Property1
        {
            get
            {
                return Messages.GetMessageText(GetPortData(), 359608);
            }
        }
```

I have to change all the bindings like this to a property since we want to replace the UI by knockoutjs.

**Now I have something like this:**

```
@Html.MyNewModifiedAnchor(myObject.AddItemProp("url"), Html.Partial("~/Views/path1/path2/Widgets/Viewtitle.title.cshtml", myObject))
```

And I am trying to convert this into a property:

```
HtmlHelper htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(?,?); //wrong I dunno how to populate ?,?
htmlHelper.MyNewModifiedAnchor(myObject.AddItemProp("url"), new MvcHtmlString(htmlHelper.Partial("~/Views/path1/path2/Widgets/Viewtitle.title.cshtml", myObject))); //even this line is error
```

- **But it doesnt work** I dont have a way to create Htmlhelper object since the constructor takes 2 arguments.

I am  not sure if I am going correct. How do I replace all such bindings by properties? Kindly guide me.